# notify_url not working anymore in PayPal for my sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I don't see any log regarding this on my rails console.
I assume that this notify_url is called at the time of payment transaction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I need more info, but:

- check that your notify_url is absolute
- check that your notify_url is a name and not an IP address

notice that:

- i experienced short periods of sandbox inactivity
- time between request and response is 30 seconds more or less in my country